# Anonymous users can not access website

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login, user-access

I have inherited a WordPress shopping website with WooCommerce. Prior to me, retailers used the website to place orders for the items to be sold in their shops. As a result, a forced login was implemented. Now the shop is opening to online-shoppers but I was not able to find the option which would allow anonymous users to access the website. Anyone not logged in visiting the website is greeted with the login form. Under **Settings > General**, everyone is allowed to register, and under **WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts and Privacy**, all options are checked under Guest checkout and Account creation. Is there somewhere else I have to look or do I have to go into code? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are too many possible ways to do this, sorry.. Is it not possible to reach out to whoever you inherited the project from and ask them?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was hoping as a last resort, to by-pass it with a code snippet.

Comment: You can do that, but it is impossible for us to tell you how or with which explicit code snippet - as that depends on how it was blocked in the beginning.

Comment: Look in the list of installed plugins - there may be another that handles the forced login. You can try disabling/re-enabling them one by one to see. It could also be in the functions.php file of your active theme.